# Share a machine on a local network without granting internet access to updates etc

Tags: networking

How would someone install a Windows 10 machine onto a local network with full sharing across the LAN and yet prohibit the machine from accessing the internet indefinately.
.
The machine is yet to be purchased. (or I may repurpose an old XP box).

Is it just a matter of assigning a fixed IP address & then blocking that IP @ the router?

Or is there some way just to block any software updates?

Just putting it out there to see if anyone can provide some advice or point me in the right direction.

Cheerz

Answer (score 0):

There are a range of ways of doing it.

One option would be to configure a firewall on that machine that only allows local traffic.

Another option would be to look into "Access Control" features on your (presumably consumer) router to block a machine reaching the Internet. These are probably going to use a MAC address rather than an IP address.

You could get more advanced with managed switches with access control lists, VLANs, etc.

It depends on what you want to achieve and how you want to manage it.

Comment: Greetings, thank you for your response, it is appreciated.  Yes it is a consumer router & I think blocking the MAC address wiill work.